# How to split large PDF file pages into separated new PDF files per page?

Tags: bash, shell, pdf

I want to split my large book PDF into separated files, ideally using bash command

**Actual :**

my-file.pdf

```
|--page1
|--page2
|--page3
|--...
```

**Excpected:**

- page1.pdf
- page2.pdf
- page3.pdf
- ...

Answer (score 2):

With **ImageMagick** which is included in most Linux distros and is available for macOS and Windows.

```
magick YourFile.pdf page%d.pdf
```

Use `convert` in place of `magick` if still using older v6 ImageMagick.

Comment: It's works but don't preserve the quality of PDF, each page is converted into image and I lose the quality of vector shapes

Comment: Correct, ImageMagick is a raster image processor and converts everything to rasters because that's the way to works. You can try setting the density before opening your input file so it rasterises at a higher quality, but it will still rasterise. That would be `magick -density 288 YourFile.pdf page%d.pdf`

Comment: To increase quality without increasing dimensions, use `magick -density 288 YourFile.pdf -resize 25% page%d.pdf` 288=4*72. So we have to reduce size by the 1/4=25%

Comment: @fmw42 Than you, I forgot that bit.